# Return in response to custom JSON, which returns a proven response to execute a stored procedure in BD Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Good afternoon I have a small query, the question is that I am running a small REST service that receives a request, and must return a custom response, in fact I already have the response, but this current response was based on a Stored Procedure, so to the answer I must return through projections in Spring Boot, the question is that I need a personalized JSON of response, but I don't know how to do it, what I see is that it would be with classes, but I have the doubt of how it would be combined with the interface that I use as a projection to retrieve and show the Stored Procedue response.

My Code

Main Class

```
package com.app.validate;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ValidateClientApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ValidateClientApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.validate.dao.ValidateClientAppRepository;
import com.app.validate.entity.ResponseVo;
import com.app.validate.request.BodyRequestComplete;

@RestController
public class ValidateClientAppController {

    @Autowired
    private ValidateClientAppRepository dao; 

    @PostMapping(value = "/ValidateClientApp",consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json") 
    public ResponseVo ValidateClient(@RequestBody BodyRequestComplete req) {
        //System.out.println(driver.getMovil()); 
        return dao.validarClienteBonificado(req.getValidateClient().getBodyRequest().getValidateClientRequest().getMovil()); 
    }

}
```

Dao

```
package com.app.validate.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.app.validate.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validate.entity.ResponseVo;

@Repository
public interface ValidateClientAppRepository extends JpaRepository<DriverBonificados, Integer> {


    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call ValidacionClienteBonificado(:movil)")
    ResponseVo validarClienteBonificado(@Param("movil") String pMovil);

}
```

ResponseVo 
(An interface is used to obtain the Stored Procedue response and be able to display it as Json)

```
package com.app.validate.entity;

public interface ResponseVo {

    String getCode();
    String getResult();
}
```

BodyRequest

```
   package com.app.validate.request;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

    public class BodyRequest {

        @JsonProperty("ValidateClientRequest")
        private ValidateClientRequest validateClientRequest;

        public ValidateClientRequest getValidateClientRequest() {
            return validateClientRequest;
        }

        public void setValidateClientRequest(ValidateClientRequest validateClientRequest) {
            this.validateClientRequest = validateClientRequest;
        }

    }
```

BodyRequestComplete

```
package com.app.validate.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class BodyRequestComplete {

    @JsonProperty("ValidateClient")
    private ValidateClient validateClient;

    public ValidateClient getValidateClient() {
        return validateClient;
    }

    public void setValidateClient(ValidateClient validateClient) {
        this.validateClient = validateClient;
    }
}
```

ValidateClient

```
package com.app.validate.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ValidateClient {

    @JsonProperty("Body")
    private BodyRequest bodyRequest;

    public BodyRequest getBodyRequest() {
        return bodyRequest;
    }

    public void setBodyRequest(BodyRequest bodyRequest) {
        this.bodyRequest = bodyRequest;
    }

}
```

ValidateClientRequest

```
package com.app.validate.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ValidateClientRequest {

    @JsonProperty("msisdn")
    private String movil;

    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }

    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }

}
```

My request

```
{
      "ValidateClient": {
        "Body": {
          "ValidateClientRequest": {
            "msisdn": "04242125890"
          }
       }
    }
}
```

My Response (current)

```
{
    "result": "Cliente aplica para bono",
    "code": "00000"
}
```

Desired Response

```
{ "ValidateClient": {
       "Body":
          {
          "detail": {
             "Code": "00000",
             "Message": "Cliente aplica para bono",
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Postman test

[image]

Structure of my code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to create another POJO with desired output and return that from service.

Change your service like below

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/ValidateClientApp",consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json") 
    public Object ValidateClient(@RequestBody BodyRequestComplete req) {
        //System.out.println(driver.getMovil()); 
        ResponseVo vo =  dao.validarClienteBonificado(req.getValidateClient().getBodyRequest().getValidateClientRequest().getMovil()); 

        return MyResponse.getMyResponse(vo);
/*
        //if you want to use Map solution then
        return MapBasedResponse.getResponse(vo);
*/
    }
```

```
public class MyResponse {

    MyValidateClient ValidateClient;

    public static MyResponse getMyResponse(ResponseVo vo) {
        Detail detail = new Detail();
        detail.setCode(vo.getCode());
        detail.setMessage(vo.getResult());

        MyBody body = new MyBody();
        body.setDetail(detail);

        MyValidateClient vc = new MyValidateClient();
        vc.setBody(body);

        MyResponse myresponse = new MyResponse();
        myresponse.setValidateClient(vc);

        return myresponse;
    }

    public MyValidateClient getValidateClient() {
        return ValidateClient;
    }

    public void setValidateClient(MyValidateClient validateClient) {
        ValidateClient = validateClient;
    }

}
class MyValidateClient {
    MyBody Body;

    public MyBody getBody() {
        return Body;
    }

    public void setBody(MyBody body) {
        Body = body;
    }
}
class MyBody {
    Detail detail;

    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}
class Detail {
    String code;
    String Message;
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

Other option is to use direct Json api to build Json String and return that. 
For example, you can create map and return map from service

```
    public static Map<String,Object> getResponse(ResponseVo vo) {
        Map<String,String> detail = new HashMap<>(2);
        detail.put("code", vo.getCode());
        detail.put("Message", vo.getResult());

        Map<String,Object> body = new HashMap<>(1);
        body.put("detail", detail);

        Map<String,Object> vc = new HashMap<>(1);
        vc.put("Body", body);

        Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>(1);
        result.put("ValidateClient", vc);

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: I do not see it clear or how I would return it in the controller, could you clarify it please? And thanks for your reply

Comment: Thank you very much, I got just what you got

Comment: The question returns me all right is that the words like body, detail, the first one returns to me in lowercase letters, and I would like the first capital letter, I don't know if this can be done?

Comment: @CesarJusto did you try Map based solution I gave? Is it returning "Body" or "body"?

Comment: With the HashMap, I return an empty JSON object by executing the code you told me, in the Response Service class, what I do is place only the HashMap code

Comment: On the other hand, with the other code everything returns to me well, but the first letter of each heading in lower case, and I would like it in capital letter

Comment: @CesarJusto my bad. I corrected Map code. Please use updated getResponse(ResponseVo vo) method and check.